# I am totally new to Extjs. please help me to complete this task

Tags: extjs

I have a single-page web application in which I need to display a grid with at least 100 records and each record should have at least 10 named attributes.

The grid should display 10 records at once and allow for pagination to the rest of the records. It should display only a part of record attributes. The complete set of attributes should be available in a separate pop-up window. The window should open upon double-clicking a record.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Along with Lorenz's answer, sencha has tons of resources and [examples available](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/index.html). Specifically the [grid panel examples](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#grids) might be good examples to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Download Sencha cmd and run `sencha generate app`

Read the MVC documentation  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/application_architecture/application_architecture.html

Look at the examples and copy paste some code (keeping in mind MVC) and you're almost done. When you have a specific question come back and ask that specific question.

Comment: I did this task. Thanks for reply @Lorenz Meyar.